# Pytesseract not converting image to text on M1 max MacBook Pro

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am using a M1 max MacBook Pro, I have installed brew and tesseract through mac's terminal and it shows that its already installed if I try to install it again. I have tried a lot of things but it's not converting the image to text. When I run the below code it only outputs Running on Mac and then ends. Also, the file that I am trying to convert is already in the source folder with name "unnamed.png" and I am using pycharm for this purpose. python version - 3.7, tesseract version - 5.2.0

```
from PIL import Image
import enum

class OS(enum.Enum):
    Mac = 0
    Windows = 1

class Language(enum.Enum):
    ENG = 'eng'
    RUS = 'rus'
    ITA = 'ita'

class ImageReader:
    def __init__(self, os: OS):
        if os == OS.Mac:
            print("Running on Mac\n")

    def extractText(self, image: str) -> str:
        img = Image.open(image)
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
        return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.2.0/bin/tesseract'
    ir = ImageReader(OS.Mac)
    text = ir.extractText('unnamed.png')
    print(text)
```

This is the output that I am getting.

```
/Users/ritessshhh/PycharmProjects/Tello_course/venv/bin/python /Users/ritessshhh/PycharmProjects/handtracking/test.py
Running on Mac



Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Good morning,

why did you put an 'r' in the statement below :
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.2.0/bin/tesseract'

can you try with the following statement :
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.2.0/bin/tesseract'